# Delete parts of Rapid eye images

Tags: google-earth-engine

What is the most convenient way to delete geometries from a rapid eye image? I want to draw a polygon and delete that part from the image. Like the opposite to a clip function, that keeps the geometry but not the rest of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this should work:

```
var masked = image.updateMask(
  image.clip(geometry).mask().not()
)
```